# Is there any way to recover Office 365 Groups after 30 days?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, office-365-groups, microsoft-forms

I have created many Microsoft Forms associated with a Office 365 Group. Somehow, another person from the organization has deleted that Office 365 group.

Now all the forms are became inaccessible.

The groups was deleted more than 30 days ago. Is there any way to get Office 365 group back?

Or any way by which I can get my Microsoft Forms back?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you delete a group, it will be retained for 30 days by default.

This 30-day period is considered a **soft-delete** because you can still restore the group.

After 30 days, the group and its associated contents are **permanently deleted and cannot be restored**.

**Microsoft documentations**:

1. [Restore a deleted Microsoft 365 group](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/create-groups/restore-deleted-group)
2. [Restore a deleted Microsoft 365 group in Azure Active Directory](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/groups-restore-deleted)

---

I will recommend to raise a support ticket with Microsoft for further information/clarification.

Comment: I have already raised a ticket with Microsoft and it has been more than 30 days but still no resolution.